# QML Qt.binding with function from c++

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I have a QML item that's created during runtime from a JavaScript.

```
function finishCreation(SetValuePropertyMain) {
    if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
        gauge = component.createObject(mainwindow, {"mainvalue": Qt.binding(function() {return SetValuePropertyMain}));
        if (gauge === null) {
            // Error Handling
            console.log("Error creating object");
        }

    } else if (component.status === Component.Error) {
        // Error Handling
        console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
    }
}
```

where **SetValuePropertyMain** is **dataSourceModel.data(dataSourceModel.index(cbx_sources.currentIndex,0),259)**

dataSourceModel is a class derived from QAbstractListModel

In the qml item that's created by the JS, is a timer that should update "mainvalue", but updated values are not passed to qml. Is Qt.Binding the wrong way for this?

Comment: Did you try `return SetValuePropertyMain();`? Try adding debug in the C++ function and maybe even inside the binding function

Comment: This is not working because the JS doenst know this function. When first calling  the js to create the QML item, the value is passed, but updating is not working